# Setting a data-driven subscription in SSRS with what I hope to be a parameter for a date/time variable

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am setting a data-driven subscription in SSRS with what I hope to be a parameter for a date/time variable.  The business requirement is that I pass a Parmenter to the report that needs to be set to yesterday's date from when the subscribed email alert is sent.

This is a query I am using in a data-driven subscription in SSRS. How to I make the following SQL query return  the previous date instead of the current system date:

```
SELECT CONVERT (date, SYSDATETIME()) as rundate
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue using the following query:

```
SELECT convert (date, DATEADD (DAY, -1 , SYSDATETIME())) as rundate
```